# Mongodb Error on running phpunit test

Tags: mongodb, phpunit

I tried to run mongdodb's driver test using phpunit as stated at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.testing.php but it seems to have a problem with a MongoInt32Test.php filew.

```
# phpunit tests/mongosuite.php

Warning: require_once(MongoInt32Test.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Documents and Settings\owner\Desktop\mongo-php-driver\tests\MongoSuite.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'MongoInt32Test.php' (include_path='.;\programming_tools\xampp-portable\php\PEAR') in C:\Documents and Settings\owner\Desktop\mongo-php-driver\tests\MongoSuite.php on line 4
```

I am using a php_mongo-1.3.1-5.4-vc9.dll and running mongodb 2.0.8 in windows xp. Anybody knows how to fix this? I can't find MongoInt32Test.php anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The PHPUnit tests in the extension are legacy tests and are no longer supported. I created a ticket, [PHP-695](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-695), to remind us to remove mention of them from the documentation. All extension tests are phpt files, and instructions for executing them are documented in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver).